# How can i make an event fire every time on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

im trying to make and the same event fire every time but it only fires once when i click "del" button

HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="todoInput" id="todoInput">
    <button class="btn">Add</button><br>
    <p class="error"></p>
    <div>
        <ul class="todos"></ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
var todos = [];

$(".btn").click(function() {
    if ($("#todoInput").val().length != 0) {
        todos.push($("#todoInput").val());
        $("#todoInput").val("");
        console.log("Novi array:", todos);
        $(".todos").html("");
        $(todos).each(function(index, val) {
            $(".todos").append(`<li value=${val}>${val}<button class="del" value=${index}>del</button></li>`);
        });

        **$(".del").click(function() {
            todos.splice($(this).val(), 1);
            $(".todos").html("");
            $(todos).each(function(index, val) {
                $(".todos").append(`<li value=${val}>${val}<button class="del" value=${index}>del</button></li>`);
            });**
        });
    } else {
        $(".error").text("Molimo unesite vrijednost.");
        console.log("Trenutni array:" ,todos);
    }
});

$("#todoInput").on("input", function() {
    if ($("#todoInput").val().length != 0 && $(".error").text("Molimo unesite vrijednost.")) {
        $(".error").text("");
    }
});
```

im trying to make and the same event fire every time but it only fires once when i click "del" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issie you have is that the `(".del").click(function() {` function is not running repeatedly and therefore not binding the `onclick` handler to it.

Perhaps an alternative method would be to create the delete function and pass in the the index of the item to delete, see below snippet:

```js
let todos = [];

function buildItems() {
  if (todos.length > 0) {
    $(".todos").html("");
    $(todos).each(function(index, val) {
      $(".todos").append(`<li value=${val}>${val}<button class="del" onclick="deleteItem(${index});" value=${index}>del</button></li>`);
    })
  } else {
    $(".todos").html("");
  }
}


function deleteItem(index) {
  todos.splice(index, 1);
  buildItems();
}

$(".btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#todoInput").val().length != 0) {
    todos.push($("#todoInput").val());
    $("#todoInput").val("");
    // console.log("Novi array:", todos);
    buildItems()

  } else {
    $(".error").text("Molimo unesite vrijednost.");
    console.log("Trenutni array:", todos);
  }
});

$("#todoInput").on("input", function() {
  if ($("#todoInput").val().length != 0 && $(".error").text("Molimo unesite vrijednost.")) {
    $(".error").text("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="todoInput" id="todoInput">
<button class="btn">Add</button><br>
<p class="error"></p>
<div>
  <ul class="todos"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We actually use on/off click to make sure the click triggers the event.
$(".btn").off ('click').on('click',function() {...}